# Hide email adress of sender when sending on behalf of

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2003, sendmail

*Situation:*

- using Microsoft Outlook 2003
- using Exchange 2007 server

*What I want to do:*

- **send email on behalf of** xyz@example.com
- want to **hide** my own exmail adress abc@example.com

I managed to have direct replies (using the answer button) to xyz@example.com. But the problem is that my own email adress is visible in sent mails. I don't want my email adress to get public.

If there is no solution for Microsoft Office 2003, is there one for Office 2007/2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook supports different identities. Take a look at this description: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918/en-us

Comment: Care to explain what the link says about "different identities"?

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand what you are meaning. But switching the user profile each time I want to send a mail on behalf as is not a practical solution. I would have to switch my profile from mail to mail (one time I want to send a mail directly and the next time I want to send a mail on behalf of a more general post box).

Comment: Outlook Express called the feature identities. Outlook 2003 calls it profiles. You have the ability to send with two different email addresses (identities/profiles). You can switch the email address by switching the identity/profile. This is the way Outlook does it. If you don't like it try another mailer. In Google Mail it is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the same problem. I just **removed** the permission to "Send on behalf" on the ESM - Exchange 2003 (the target sender was a public folder). Then on the public folder "directory rights" I **added** the sending user with the "Send As" permision.
Worked quite well!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue in Outlook 2007/2010 I decided to build my own add-on to accomplish it. I just published an article describing the problem and the solution and a link to download the free add-in: http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/06/06/removing-the-on-behalf-of-message-from-outlook/

I will check if I can make it run on Outlook 2003 and be back soon.