# Outlook 2010 Remove "on behalf of" without multiple profiles

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'd like to remove the "on behalf of" from my emails in Outlook 2010. It appears when I use the from drop down while sending an email:

[image]

When I send an email from the address the outlook profile was created with, it will appear as this:

> Name

however when I use the from option, it will appear as this:

> Name < Name@Example.com > on behalf of OtherEmail@Example.com

Often I use this other email adress(s) to hide my main one to protect from spammers (I dispose of the address after the fact), but this foils the plan.

My research shows that most people create multiple outlook profiles, but in my case that would require too many profiles and too much work. I just wan't to remove this part of the header, without complicating my setup:

> **Name < Name@Example.com > on behalf of** OtherEmail@Example.com

This is **not** a duplicate of this: [Hide email adress of sender when sending on behalf of](https://superuser.com/questions/279955/hide-email-adress-of-sender-when-sending-on-behalf-of), the accepted answer won't work here, and the question is much much vaguer then this one.

Comment: That is much better! I will remove my comments to reduce clutter in the comments.

Comment: This [article](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/06/06/removing-the-on-behalf-of-message-from-outlook/) points to an add-in to Outlook that supposedly solves the problem.

Comment: @harrymc It still give the email in the header :/

Comment: According to a comment on the article : "you have to install the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44074). Once I installed that then the add-on worked."

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to what you're asking for, but it might be worth checking out (if you use Gmail with Outlook): http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

Comment: Another idea is to delete your name from the account, leaving only your email address. Without a name, Outlook might not have enough information to write that header.

Comment: Tried that.... failed...

Comment: @harrymc I'll have to try that

Comment: @Vinayak Thanks, but I'm not using gmail

Comment: @harrymc I installed MVS 2012 for Office, and still no luck... :/

Comment: I think that what you want is only possible when using an Exchange server or Active Directory. Otherwise, if that header is a big headache, use another email client such as Thunderbird, or use Gmail.

Comment: @harrymc Okay :/

Answer (score 1):

Outlook adds the On Behalf Of header to the message in order to protect it
from being branded as spam by some ISPs or email clients.

Unfortunately, it seems as though turning this mechanism off is only possible
when using Exchange server or Active Directory.

The article [Send On Behalf and Send As](http://www.shudnow.net/2007/08/12/send-on-behalf-and-send-as/) shows three ways of enabling
On Behalf Of using Exchange.

The article [How to grant Send On Behalf Of permission](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/msexchange/exch_howto_grant_send_on_behalf_of.htm)
also add how to grant On Behalf Of via Active Directory.

However, there does not seem any method in stand-alone Outlook
to avoid the On Behalf Of header being automatically sent.
If that header is a problem, perhaps using another email client
such as Thunderbird, or Gmail, will solve it.

Comment: You can have the bounty, I see no point in having it go to waste, and you where helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an add-on for solving this issue and does not require Microsoft Exchange. The article and the application is available [here](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/06/06/removing-the-on-behalf-of-message-from-outlook/).

Answer (score 0):

First in Gmail add your non Gmail account on settings under "send mail as:"
[Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz85H.jpg)

Then in Outlook on Account Settings change the email address:
[Outlook 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ET20.jpg)
 Now, because Outlook uses Gmail SMPT other than your non-gmail provider, it doesn't add the "On behalf of" to the header.